# How to assign every element of a data frame at once?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, vectorization

I have `OG_df` which is:

```
           Symbol Order  Shares
Date                           
2011-01-10   AAPL   BUY    1500
2011-01-13   AAPL  SELL    1500
2011-01-13    IBM   BUY    4000
2011-01-26   GOOG   BUY    1000
2011-02-02    XOM  SELL    4000
2011-02-10    XOM   BUY    4000
2011-03-03   GOOG  SELL    1000
2011-03-03   GOOG  SELL    2200
2011-05-03    IBM   BUY    1500
2011-06-03    IBM  SELL    3300
2011-06-10   AAPL   BUY    1200
2011-08-01   GOOG   BUY      55
2011-08-01   GOOG  SELL      55
2011-12-20   AAPL  SELL    1200
2011-12-21   AAPL   BUY      20
2011-12-27   GOOG   BUY    2200
2011-12-28    IBM  SELL    2200
```

I also have `df_prices` which is:

```
          AAPL     IBM    GOOG    XOM     SPY  CASH
2011-01-10  340.99  143.41  614.21  72.02  123.19   1.0
2011-01-11  340.18  143.06  616.01  72.56  123.63   1.0
...            ...     ...     ...    ...     ...   ...
2011-11-15  387.17  186.44  616.56  77.62  124.10   1.0
2011-11-16  383.13  184.33  611.47  76.79  122.13   1.0
2011-11-17  375.80  183.45  600.87  76.41  120.19   1.0
2011-11-18  373.34  182.97  594.88  76.45  120.06   1.0
2011-11-21  367.43  179.26  580.94  75.48  117.78   1.0
2011-11-22  374.90  179.09  580.00  74.61  117.31   1.0
[245 rows x 6 columns]
```

I set `date_range = pd.date_range(OG_df.index.min(), OG_df.index.max())` and then

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(0, df_prices.index, columns=list(df_prices))
```

Say you have `vals = df1.values` which is:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 ..., 
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

with shape `(245, 6)`

I can also get

```
cols = np.array([df1.columns.get_loc(c) for c in OG_df.Symbol])
```

`cols` returns `[0 0 1 2 3 3 2 2 1 1 0 2 2 0 0 2 1]`

`OG_df.Symbol` is `['AAPL' 'IBM' 'GOOG' 'XOM']`, so as you can see, there are 4 different columns for 17 different rows in `OG_df`.

I also have

```
rows = np.arange(len(df1))
```

I want to do something like `vals[rows, cols] = some_variable` but that returns:

```
IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (245,) (17,)
```

because `rows` is length `17` and `cols` is length `245`.

I want to fill every cell in `df1` based on `some_variable` (which is different every time).

```
order = np.where(orders_df.Order.values == 'BUY', -1, 1)

some_variable = OG_df.Shares.values * order

len(some_variable) = 17
```

How do I go about this?

Also, I do not want to assign `some_variable` to the `CASH` of `df1`.

Example output:

```
              AAPL     IBM    GOOG    XOM     SPY  CASH
2011-01-10  1500        0       0.     0       0.   N/A
2011-01-11  0           0.      0.     0       0.   N/A
2011-01-12  0           0       0      0       0    N/A
2011-01-13  -1500       4000.   0.     0.      0.   N/A
```

Comment: `df[:] = vals`?

Comment: I get `ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable`

Comment: It would help so much to have access to your actual data. Or maybe a [mcve].

Comment: Ohk its hard to understand what you are trying to convey. Do you want to replace the existing values of certain columns with new values?

Comment: I initialized them all to zeros. I want to set all the columns except the last one equal to values from another data frame column. I will fill each row with that variable.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Give me a second to get that

Comment: Maybe you are looking for merge. Please put some data so we better understand what your actual prob is.

Comment: Also, what is `some_variable`.shape?

Comment: Expected output would be nice too

Comment: Ohk so you want to put OG_df.Shares data in new dataframe under respective column and index.

Comment: @Bharathshetty Yes that is correct.

Comment: @Bharathshetty Except, remember that the last column of `df1` will not be `some_variable`

Comment: There are duplicates like two shares for same symbol and date which one do you want to keep.

Comment: Are you talking about `2011-03-03   GOOG  SELL    1000` and 
`2011-03-03   GOOG  SELL    2200` in `OG_df`? I need both of them in my calculations.

Comment: Sorry, it still isn't clear... can you show your expected output for about 5 rows?

Comment: How can you add that into to one particular cell of new dataframe . As a list?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ hes coming very near to pivot and reindex with fillna(0) but duplicate data is still a problem.

Comment: @Bharathshetty If you can understand what OP wants, power to you. I certainly can't.

Comment: I added new information. Sorry, I wasn't sure what was too much and too little information. This will be a learning experience for me.

Comment: I added a solution using pivot_table. You can use `aggfunc= custom func` currenlty it will add mean of repeated data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to recreate pivot_table, reindex. i.e

```
df = OG_df.copy()

df['Shares'] = np.where(df['Order'] == 'BUY',df['Shares']*-1,df['Shares']) 

ndf = df.pivot_table(columns='Symbol',values='Shares',index='Date')\
       .reindex(date_range).fillna(0).assign(CASH=np.nan)
```

Sample output based on given data.

```
    
    Symbol    AAPL  GOOG     IBM  XOM  CASH
2011-01-10 -1500.0   0.0     0.0  0.0   NaN
2011-01-11     0.0   0.0     0.0  0.0   NaN
2011-01-12     0.0   0.0     0.0  0.0   NaN
2011-01-13  1500.0   0.0 -4000.0  0.0   NaN
2011-01-14     0.0   0.0     0.0  0.0   NaN
2011-01-15     0.0   0.0     0.0  0.0   NaN
2011-01-16     0.0   0.0     0.0  0.0   NaN
2011-01-17     0.0   0.0     0.0  0.0   NaN
2011-01-18     0.0   0.0     0.0  0.0   NaN
2011-01-19     0.0   0.0     0.0  0.0   NaN
```

The missing `SPY` column will be added automatically if there is an occurance of `SPY` symbol in `OG_df`.

Comment: You are missing the case where a value could be negative based on the order. `order = np.where(orders_df.Order.values == 'BUY', -1, 1)`

Comment: whats the value of `impact`.

Comment: I got rid of it for now. It doesn’t matter right now.

Comment: I updated the solution. In pandas its better you put sample data and expected output with bit of logic you are trying to implement, what you tried.

Comment: What if I wanted the same number of rows in `df_prices` and `ndf`?

Comment: That last row doesn't exist in `df_prices` and shouldn't in `ndf`

Comment: Instead of date range reindex df_prices.index